# Path Mapping on Route 53 domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am trying to do a path mapping on a route 53 recordset to the CloudFront instead of a domain name and i have no clue on where to locate the option or even if its possible?

I created a S3 bucket with static hosting enabled, routed it through CloudFront and mapped it to route 53.

What i didnt have trouble doing was,

```
www.test.com (route 53) -> xxx.cloudfront.net -> s3 bucket(origin)
```

But i want to be able to do this,

```
www.test.com/api (route 53) -> xxx.cloudfront.net -> s3 bucket(origin)
```

is there an option hidden somewhere i am missing to map paths?

*PS*: I couldn't find any related question asked on the stack, if there is please point me towards it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route 53 is specifically for DNS configuration, whilst it allows you to resolve hostnames to IP addresses it does not have route based routing. This would be a layer 7 feature once the hostname has been resolved.

If you want path based routing within your CloudFront distribution you have the option to create multiple behaviours specifying an origin per each behaviour. The behaviour requires you to set a path mapping that when matched will use that origin.

For more information take a look at the [Can I use a single CloudFront web distribution to serve content from multiple origins using multiple behaviors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/) article.